# ReactiveUI ViewModel Unit Testing

Tags: xamarin, mono, xamarin-studio, reactiveui

I have been trying to get rid of iOS/Android Test Harness and make my VM Unit Tests run directly on XS/VS test runners, because:
1) It's WAAAAY faster then loading up the Harness every time
2) Makes it easier to run on VSTS

I know that I can't run it from a PCL directly due the "Bait & Switch", so after reading @kentcb post http://kent-boogaart.com/blog/using-the-visual-studio-test-runner-for-mobile-development, I decided to give a try to run it on a net45 test project and see how it goes, but still no success so far, I'm getting some errors like:

> System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for
>   'ReactiveUI.ReactiveNotifyPropertyChangedMixin' threw an exception.
>   ----> System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'ReactiveUI.RxApp' threw an exception.   ---->
>   System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for
>   'ReactiveUI.CreatesCommandBindingViaEvent' threw an exception.
>
> at ReactiveUI.WhenAnyMixin.WhenAny[TSender,TRet,T1,T2] (TSender
>   This, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[TDelegate] property1,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[TDelegate] property2,
>   System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] selector) [0x00000] in
>   <4aefaa9175534ecd872465be2cbe3a19>:0    at
>   RxUIVIewModelUnitTesting.ViewModels.LoginViewModel..ctor
>   (RxUIVIewModelUnitTesting.Services.IAuthenticationSystem
>   authenticationSystem, System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler
>   scheduler) [0x000b1] in
>   /Users/giusepecasagrande/Git/Giusepe/RxUIVIewModelUnitTesting/src/RxUIVIewModelUnitTesting.ViewModels/LoginViewModel.cs:58
>   at
>   RxUIVIewModelUnitTesting.ViewModels.UnitTests.LoginViewModelTest.Setup
>   () [0x00020] in
>   /Users/giusepecasagrande/Git/Giusepe/RxUIVIewModelUnitTesting/src/RxUIVIewModelUnitTesting.ViewModels.UnitTests/LoginViewModelTest.cs:28
>   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke
>   (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)   at
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj,
>   System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder
>   binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo
>   culture) [0x00038] in
>   /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305
>
> --TypeInitializationException   at ReactiveUI.ReactiveNotifyPropertyChangedMixin..cctor () [0x00020] in
>   <4aefaa9175534ecd872465be2cbe3a19>:0 
>   --TypeInitializationException   at ReactiveUI.Registrations+<>c.b__0_7 () [0x00000] in
>   <4aefaa9175534ecd872465be2cbe3a19>:0    at
>   ReactiveUI.DependencyResolverMixins+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0
>   (System.Func`1[TResult] f, System.Type t) [0x00000] in
>   <4aefaa9175534ecd872465be2cbe3a19>:0    at
>   ReactiveUI.Registrations.Register (System.Action`2[T1,T2]
>   registerFunction) [0x00149] in <4aefaa9175534ecd872465be2cbe3a19>:0
>   at ReactiveUI.DependencyResolverMixins.InitializeReactiveUI
>   (Splat.IMutableDependencyResolver resolver) [0x00028] in
>   <4aefaa9175534ecd872465be2cbe3a19>:0    at
>   ReactiveUI.RxApp+<>c.<.cctor>b__0_0 () [0x0000d] in
>   <4aefaa9175534ecd872465be2cbe3a19>:0    at
>   Splat.Locator.RegisterResolverCallbackChanged (System.Action callback)
>   [0x00039] in <66ec575cc13f4eaea0cbad3add11aa6e>:0    at
>   ReactiveUI.RxApp..cctor () [0x00010] in
>   <4aefaa9175534ecd872465be2cbe3a19>:0

So I put a sample project with this happening (https://github.com/GiusepeCasagrande/RxUIVIewModelUnitTesting), any help here would be appreciate, even if it's to "no way that's gonna work", because then I'll just move back to Test Harness and start using Cake for VSTS.

edit: I forgot to say: I'm running this on a Mac with XS. So I asked a friend to test the same solution on a Windows/VS and it works! Now seems that I have found some Mac/mono limitations here.

Comment: I can confirm it's happening with mono 4.8.0 as well.

Comment: Let's see what Xamarin says: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=51782

Comment: Is the error from running within Xamarin Studio? Just wondering if the same error occurs when running from the command line using a recent NUnit. That would indicate a problem in Mono if it fails the same way from the command line.

Comment: Yes, it happened when running from the command line as well.